# Writing a rails query where an association meets a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Model A which `belongs_to` Model B

Model B has a boolean field `flag`

I want to find all A where A.bs.flag == true

I am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mongo you can try:

```
A.where( :b.in => B.where( :flag => true ).map(&:id) )
```

'b' is the name of relation in A ( belongs_to b ).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
A.joins(:b).where(bs: { flat: true })
```

note that `bs` is used to note the plural form of B.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the following query to get all the A's form B's whose flag is set to true.

@a = A.bs.where(:flag => true)